# Are side-effects in Array's "every", or "some" bad?

Tags: javascript, bad-code, side-effect

I've always been taught that having side-effects in an `if` condition are bad. What I mean is;

```
if (conditionThenHandle()) {
    // do effectively nothing
}
```

... as opposed to;

```
if (condition()) {
    handle();
}
```

... and I understand that, and my collegues are happy because I don't do it, and we all go home at 17:00 on a Friday and everyone has a merry weekend.

Now, ECMAScript5 introduced methods like `every()` and `some()` to `Array`, and I find them very useful. They're cleaner than `for (;;;)`'s, give you another scope, *and* make the element accessible by a variable.

However when validating input, I more-often-than-not find myself using `every`/`some` in the condition to validate the input, then use `every`/`some` *again* in the body to convert the input into a usable model;

```
if (input.every(function (that) {
    return typeof that === "number";
})) {
    input.every(function (that) {
        // Model.findById(that); etc
    }
} else {
    return;
}
```

... when what I *want* to be doing is;

```
if (!input.every(function (that) {
    var res = typeof that === "number";

    if (res) {
        // Model.findById(that); etc.
    }

    return res;
})) {
    return;
}
```

... which gives me side-effects in an `if`, condition, which is bad.

In comparison, this is the code would look with with an old `for (;;;)`;

```
for (var i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
    var curr = input[i];

    if (typeof curr === "number") {
        return;
    }

    // Model.findById(curr); etc.
}
```

---

My questions are:

1. Is this definitely a bad practice?
2. Am I (mis|ab)using `some` and `every` (*should* I be using a `for(;;;)` for this?)
3. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Every and some as well as filter,map, and reduce are queries, they have no side effects, if they do you're abusing them.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: So doesn't that make them toothless more often than not? 9/10, if I use `some`, I want to do *something* with the element, if I use `every`, I want to do something to all of those elements... `some` and `every` don't let me access that information, so either I can't use them, *or* I have to add side-effects.

Comment: No. When I refer to side effects I mean inside the head of the if not the body. Inside the body you can modify it any way you'd like. Just don't mutate the object inside the callback you pass to some/when.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: But that's exactly my point. If I use `some` in my `if` condition to determine whether a certain element in the array exhibits a certain property, 9/10 I need to operate ***on*** that element in my `if` body; now, as `some` doesn't tell me *which* of the elements exhibited the property (just "one did"), I can either use `some` *again* in the body (O(2n)), *or* I can just perform the operation inside the *if* condition (which is bad, because its a side-effect within the head).

Comment: ... the same applies for `every` as well, of course.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. You can mutate it in the body, it's what the condition is usually for. It's more expressive than for loops and much more readable most times. Which is by the way what DeadMG said, you should accept his answer

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: The mutation is only in the body *if* I replicate the `some` or `every` loop in the `if` body *as well* as the `if` head. If I use only *one* `some` or `every` loop, then the `mutation` occurs in the `every`/`some` body, ***but*** the `if` head. Are you therefore saying that I shouldn't mind about using `each`/ `some` twice, or making a point I've entirely missed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7449/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-isaac)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your point correctly, you seem to be mis-using or abusing `every` and `some` but it's a little unavoidable if you want to change the elements of your arrays directly.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you're trying to do is find out if some or every element in your sequence exhibits a certain condition then modify those elements.  Also, your code seems to be applying something to all items until you find one that doesn't pass the predicate and I don't think that's what you mean to be doing.  Anyways.

Let's take your first example (slightly modified)

```
if (input.every(function (that) {
    return typeof that === "number";
})) {
    input.every(function (that) {
        that.foo();
    }
} else {
    return;
}
```

What you're doing here actually goes a little against the spirit of the some/every/map/reduce/filter/etc concepts.  `Every` isn't meant to be used to affect every item that conforms to something, rather it should only be used to tell you if every item in a collection does.  If you want to apply a function to all items for which a predicate evaluates to true, the "good" way to do it is

```
var filtered = array.filter(function(item) {
    return typeof item === "number";
});

var mapped = filtered.map(function(item) {
    return item.foo(); //provided foo() has no side effects and returns a new object of item's type instead.  See note about foreach below.
});
```

Alternatively, you could use `foreach` instead of map to modify the items in-place.

The same logic applies to `some`, basically:

- You use `every` to test if all elements in an array pass some test.
- You use `some` to test if at least one element in an array passes some
  test.
- You use `map` to return a new array containing 1 element (which
  is the result of a function of your choice) for every element in an
  input array.
- You use `filter` to return an array of length 0 < `length` < `initial array length` elements, all contained in the original array    and all
  passing the supplied predicate test.
- You use `foreach` if you want map but in-place
- You use `reduce` if you want to combine the results of an array in a single object result (which could be an array but doesn't have to).

The more you use them (and the more you write LISP code), the more you realize how they are related and how it's even possible to emulate/implement one with the others.  What's powerful with these queries and what's really interesting is their semantics, and how they really push you towards eliminating harmful side-effects in your code.

**EDIT** (in light of comments):
So let's say you want to validate that every element is an object and convert them to an Application Model if they're all valid.  One way to do this in a single pass would be:

```
var dirty = false;
var app_domain_objects = input.map(function(item) {
    if(validate(item)) {
        return new Model(item);
    } else {
        dirty = true; //dirty is captured by the function passed to map, but you know that :)
    }
});
if(dirty) {
    //your validation test failed, do w/e you need to
} else {
    //You can use app_domain_objects
}
```

This way, when an object doesn't pass validation, you still keep iterating through the entire array, which would be slower than just validating with `every`.  However, most of the time your array will be valid (or I should hope so), so in most cases you'll perform a single pass over your array and end up with a usable array of Application Model objects.  Semantics will be respected, side-effects avoided and everyone will be happy!

Note that you could also write your own query, similar to foreach, which would apply a function to all members of an array  and returns true/false if they all pass a predicate test.  Something like:

```
function apply_to_every(arr, predicate, func) {
    var passed = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        if(predicate(arr[i])) {
            func(arr[i]);
        } else {
            passed = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return passed;
}
```

Although that would modify the array in place.

I hope this helps, it was very fun to write.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not necessarily trying to modify the elements *in place* per-se; in my actual code, I'm receiving a JSON-formatted array of objects, so I'm first *validating* the input `if (input.every())`, to check that each element *is* an object (`typeof el === "object && el !== null`) etc, *then* if that validates, I want to convert each element into the respective Application Model (which, now you mention `map()` I could use `input.map(function (el) { return new Model(el); });`; but not necessarily *in place*.

Comment: .. but see that even with `map()` I'm having to iterate over the array twice; once to validate, and another to convert. However, using a standard `for(;;;)` loop, I could do this using one iteration, but I can't find a way to apply `every`, `some`, `map` or `filter` in this scenario, and perform only ***one*** pass, without having undesired-side-effects or otherwise introducing bad-practice.

Comment: @Isaac Alright, sorry for the delay, I understand your situation more clearly now.  I'll edit my answer to add some stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer; it's been really helpful :).

Answer (score -1):

The side effects are not in the if condition, they are in the if's body. You have only determined whether or not to execute that body in the actual condition. There is nothing wrong with your approach here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Sorry, but either I've misunderstood your answer, or you've misinterpreted the code... everything in my code snippet is within the `if` condition, with only the `return` being inside the `if`'s body; obviously I'm talking about the code sample preceeded by "*what want to be doing is;*...

Comment: Sorry, @Issac's side effects are indeed in the `if` condition.